# React native dynamically build a tree

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, tree, dynamic-programming

I am building a react native application. It's basically just a tree with categories and sub-categories and then pdf documents as below.

A tree like,

```
- Category 1
    + Sub-category 1
    + Sub-category 2
        + Name of pdf document 1
    + Sub-category 3
        + Name of pdf document 1
        + Name of pdf document 2
        + Name of pdf document 3
+ Category 2
```

The tree with the documents is on a server with an Express web App so running nodeJS. 
The thing is that we don't know the number of categories, sub-categories and final documents on the tree. So I think we have to build that tree dynamically.

Every time we go into a category we could ask the server what's in the folder and display them but I don't know how to achieve that.
I don't know how to ask the server what are the folders/files in my current category/sub-category.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: where is you actual problem with it? you may illustrate it with some code.

Comment: The question is too vague. How do you ask a server what's in a folder? You make an api for it. Or use a library that spits out an api for it. The question has less to do with react and more to do with whatever software your server is running. Is your server running on node.js? Python? PHP?

Comment: Too vague. We really need to see what you've coded so far to help. I'm assuming the category structure here but you could get a flat list via API `endpoint A` then build the tree minus the files using recursion in your UI. If this was in an accordian style UI component - when the user expands a 'bottom' category you could then call `endpoint B` which will get you the list of files for said category and update the UI.

Comment: Ok so you're right I have to build an API to know what files are there, I was just not having it. Thank you.